# How do you use a case statement to make date comparisons (> or <) in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm getting an error on the greater than operator in the case statement. What am I missing here?

```
DECLARE @ODS_LOAN_MAXDATE DATE, @MAX_MAINTENANCE DATE, @MAX_TRANS DATE, @ODS_LOAN_Count int 

SELECT @MAX_MAINTENANCE = MAX(DATE_MAINTENANCE_LAST) FROM FISERV_ODS..LOAN_MASTER_FILE
SELECT @MAX_TRANS = MAX(DATE_TRANS_LAST) FROM FISERV_ODS..LOAN_MASTER_FILE

SELECT CASE @ODS_LOAN_MAXDATE
    WHEN @MAX_MAINTENANCE > @MAX_TRANS
        THEN @MAX_MAINTENANCE
    ELSE @MAX_TRANS 
END 
FROM FISERV_ODS..LOAN_MASTER_FILE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @MAX_MAINTENANCE > @MAX_TRANS
        THEN @MAX_MAINTENANCE
    ELSE @MAX_TRANS 
END
```